# Where is the loop infinity?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, momentjs

I find myself with an infinite loop error but I don’t see where it is. That’s when I add class.

**template :**

```
  <tr class="listOfDay">
    <td>Jour de la semaine</td>
    <td v-for="day in nbDaysInMonth" :key="index" :class="{weekend: isWeekend}">{{dayOfWeek(day,index)}}</td>
  </tr>
```

**script :**

```
data: () {
   isWeekend: false,
},
methods : {
  dayOfWeek(day) {
    var d = moment(new Date(this.currentYear + '-' + this.nbMonth + '-' + day)).day();
    if(d === 5 || d === 6) {
      this.isWeekend = true
    } else {
      this.isWeekend = false
    }
    return this.days[d]
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a reproduction on https://codesandbox.io/ ?

Comment: First of all, `this.nbDaysInMonth`, `this.currentYear`, `this.nbMonth` and `this.days` seems undefined in your script example.

Comment: Michael is right, it's re-rendering because you're using changing the value `isWeekend` during render, which is causing the infinite loop. If you'd like more input on how to solve this issue though, you'll need to provide more code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're changing `isWeekend` as the component is rendered, therefore causing the component to rerender, I believe this is causing the infinite loop.

Don't calculate `isWeekend` as part of `dayOfWeek`. I think the best solution would be to create another method.

EDIT: as suggested in a comment, using computed values is probably an even better solution.

Comment: also avoid using methods where you can use `computed` values. Reduces issues with mutablility and improves rendering efficiency.

Comment: Yeah, probably even better, but I'm not overly familiar with Vue. I've seen the same (anti)pattern in React though so recognized it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I create two methods.
Template : `:class="{weekend: isWeekend(day)}">{{dayOfWeek(day)}}` 
Script : `dayOfWeek(day) {
        var d = moment(new Date(this.currentYear + '-' + this.nbMonth + '-' + day)).day();
        return this.days[d]
      },
      isWeekend(day) {
        return this.dayOfWeek(day) === "S" || this.dayOfWeek(day) === "D"
      }`